# Grails 2.3.8 Internationalization coded strings

Tags: grails

I don't understand why some strings in my messages.properties files won't show in my gsp. More exactly, the show in term of the **key name** in the file not the **value**.

For example, this string in my messages.properties:

```
gtunes.store.subtitle=Your online music store and storage service!
```

is showing up on the gsp where I have this line of code:

```
<h1><g:message code='gtunes.store.subtitle'/></h1>
```

simply as:

```
gtunes.store.subtitle
```

My code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/Moe_B/gtunes/src/7fbc037d8b8766a865a3283b02610593940d500e/?at=Tag-Library).

Comment: Can you reword your question or provide an example? As it stands right now it's not clear what you are asking about.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Question edited to provide more detail. I hope it helps.

Comment: Are you sure that the 2 keys match case-sensitively?

Comment: @Dónal What I have pasted above is directly from my code so yes, I think my spelling is ok. One thing though, I am actually following along a book (older book) where source code project is from Grails 2.0.4, I modernized to Grails 2.3.8, don't know if that matters.

Comment: @AnonymousHuman if you have multiple `mesages*.properties` files, can you check if the value of the key is set to `gtunes.store.subtitle` in any of them?

Comment: Instead of single quotes try double quotes: `<h1><g:message code="gtunes.store.subtitle" /></h1>`

Comment: @JoshuaMoore It was double as when I downloaded the source code and I was having this issue, then per experimentation I decided to try single quotes, but no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your app and the reason for the error is because there's no message with this key configured in [messages.properties](https://bitbucket.org/Moe_B/gtunes/src/7fbc037d8b8766a865a3283b02610593940d500e/grails-app/i18n/messages.properties?at=Tag-Library).

If you try to render a message for a key that doesn't exist, the key is displayed instead.

Comment: Isn't it on line 70 of messages.properties?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore something odd is happening. If you run `git clone https://bitbucket.org/Moe_B/gtunes.git` the contents of `messages.properties` are not the same as what you see in the URL I posted

Comment: @Dónal I can see in my IDE that line 70 has that message code and key. Might there be some hidden characters in the file causing this anomaly? I copied the file straight from the source down load. My version hasn't been through a down/upload.

Comment: @Dónal, Ok this is super weird. Few hours later I just decided to try again and all I did was cut and paste those message-key lines again and it's working! Messages are rendering correctly. I have no clue what that was. I am marking your answer correct because it led me to the idea to cut and paste. Thanks.